# How to incoming call detect when application closed in android using service and receiver

Tags: android

```
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    try
    {
        if(intent.getStringExtra("Number")!=null)
        {
            MobileNo=intent.getStringExtra("Number");
            Log.i("MObileNo", MobileNo);
            MainActivity.CheckPaymentGivenOrNot(MobileNo,getApplicationContext());
        }   
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //MainActivity.CheckPaymentGivenOrNot("8140499976",getApplicationContext());    
    }

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
{
     Log.d("startttttttttttttttt", "start Service");

     ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), CallReceiver.class);
     PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

     pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, 
       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP); 
     IntentFilter intentfilter=new IntentFilter();
        intentfilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
        registerReceiver(cr, intentfilter);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent("StartKilledService"));


}

@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    Log.d("hello", "hello");
    h = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            //sendBroadcast(new Intent("StartKilledService"));

        }
    };
    t = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            while(b)
            {
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                    h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {

                }
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    super.onCreate();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), CallReceiver.class);
     PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
     pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, 
       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    //sendBroadcast(new Intent("StartKilledService"));
     super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

i have define this service class i am so tired because when i application close service not start and service killed automatically and not detect call incoming please help me.

Answer (score 1):

No need to create any Service. Just Create a BroadcastReceiver like this:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


    }

    public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String incomingNumber){
                switch (state) {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                        Log.d("DEBUG", "CALL_STATE_IDLE : " + incomingNumber);
                        // CALL_STATE_IDLE;
                        break;

                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                        // CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
                        Log.d("DEBUG", "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK : " + incomingNumber);
                        break;

                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                        Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING : " + incomingNumber);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
        }


    }
}
```

Add the user-permission to Read phone state in Menifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

And put this inside your  tag in Menifest file:

```
        <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

If you still want to use service and facing problem that service is not starting on phone BOOT then follow these steps:

First, you need the permission in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Also add these to manifest file:

```
<service android:name=".MyService" android:label="My Service">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.myapp.MyService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<receiver
    android:name=".receiver.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
    android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then use the BroadcastReceiver to Restart your service on phone BOOT event:

```
public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i closed the app then not detect any call i am very tried please help me my phone is xiomi prime 2

Comment: then call can detect my app when application closed in recent activity tray in my phone

Comment: @Narendratalapara create a broadcast receiver that will be called always when a calling option is performed. No matter you restart phone or keep running phone, it always work. Please try the above CallReceiver broadcast receiver code.

Comment: i am very tired with this but not working broadcast reciver when call is incoming when my app has closed

Comment: please any other idea please

Comment: thats why i used service in that when application closed in recent tray beacuse i wnat when call is incoming then i know which number is coming and match number my app

Comment: Any Idea why not working broadcast receiver after app closed in 6.0+